# Anchor and group repetition

Tags: .net, regex

Consider this regex:

```
(?:([A-Z][0-9a-z]*)+?)
```

When applied aplied to the string "A1BaaC2d", it gives me 3 groups: "A1", "Baa", and "C2d"

However when I apply the start and end string anchors, ie ^(?:([A-Z][0-9a-z]*)+?)$ it no longer works correctly.  I'd guess this is a referencing issue (hense the extra grouping which i've tried as non-capturing and atomic).  But I can't quite work it out.  How do I get my groups and validate that the total string does not have any leading or trailing chars.

FYI this is a .net regular expression.

Comment: Validation works correctly. There is no problem with your regex. Not sure, but I think you have to get the group separately from validation.

Comment: Can you show us how you used it? I can't really believe that one group gives you three capturing matches.

Comment: @Bergi: I think he's talking about three consecutive *matches* of the whole regex; see my answer.

Comment: Alan is correct.  I was looking for consecutive matches.  Alan correctly determined a flaw in my questions vocabulary - that i was actually looking for captures relating to a group rather than groups themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's pare this down to the essentials:

```
([A-Z][0-9a-z]*)+
```

(I got rid of the outer, non-capturing group because it was having no effect on the results, and I temporarily removed the `?` from the quantifier.)  What you've got there is a regex with one capturing group.  The subexpression within that group must match at least once, because of the `+` quantifier, but quantifiers are greedy by default, so it actually matches your input three times.  Here's the breakdown:

```
Match 1 = A1BaaC2d
Group 1 = C2d
Capture 1 = A1
Capture 2 = Baa
Capture 3 = C2d
```

("Group 1" refers to the *final* value captured by that group.  In most regex flavors/tools, that's all the info you would get; .NET is unique in that it allows you to break out all the intermediate Captures as well.)

However, you used the non-greedy version of the quantifier, `+?`:

```
    ([A-Z][0-9a-z]*)+?
```

It still has to match (and capture) `[A-Z][0-9a-z]*` at least once, but now it stops right there unless something forces it to continue.  Nothing does, so you get three separate *Matches*, each containing one *Capture*:

```
Match 1 = A1
Group 1 = A1
Capture 1 = A1

Match 1 = Baa
Group 1 = Baa
Capture 1 = Baa

Match 1 = C2d
Group 1 = C2d
Capture 1 = C2d
```

Then you added the anchors:

```
^([A-Z][0-9a-z]*)+?$
```

Now, each match must start at the beginning of the string and end at the end of the string.  To achieve that, the regex engine overrides the non-greediness of the `+?`, and you're back to one Match with three Captures:

```
Match 1 = A1BaaC2d
Group 1 = C2d
Capture 1 = A1
Capture 2 = Baa
Capture 3 = C2d
```

Below is the final version of the code I used to generate this output.  Be aware that you don't really need to use a non-greedy regex; `^([A-Z][0-9a-z]*)+$` will work just as well.

```
static void Main()
{
  string source = "A1BaaC2d";
  Regex r = new Regex(@"^([A-Z][0-9a-z]*)+?$");
  foreach (Match m in r.Matches(source))
  {
    int x = 1;
    Console.WriteLine(@"Match {0} = {1}", x++, m.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(@"Group 1 = {0}", m.Groups[1]);
    int y = 1;
    foreach (Capture c in m.Groups[1].Captures)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(@"Capture {0} = {1}", y++, c.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer and frankly I wouldn't have beleived it without your posted example since you're using the regex I started with.  I had totally forgotten about the "Capture" class which is not supported in most of the regex testers that I used and that sent me down the wrong road.